# Select statement with a where clause and add 'comment' in another column

Tags: sql-server, select, where-clause

I need some help to add a ‘comment’ in an additional column together with a select statement with a where clause.

**CURRENT CODE**

*First Statement*

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Dep]        = 'M'      AND 
                            ([Join M]   <> [Join B] OR   
                            [Resign M]  <> [Resign Date Beneficiary]) 
GO
```

*Second Statement*

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Join B]   < [Resign B]  AND
                            ([Join M]  > [Join B]    OR 
                            [Resign M] < [Resign B])
GO
```

This is two different select statements, however I would like to combine both outputs into one table.

**WRONG CODE - (example to explain)**

*First Statement*

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Dep]        = 'M'      AND 
                            ([Join M]   <> [Join B] OR   
                            [Resign M]  <> [Resign Date Beneficiary]) 
SET AS [Comment] = 'Main'
GO
```

*Second Statement*

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [Join B]   < [Resign B]  AND
                            ([Join M]  > [Join B]    OR 
                            [Resign M] < [Resign B])
SET AS [Comment] = 'Date'
GO
```

The requirement is to add an additional column to the output and add a 'comment' in the field, also to combine both outputs in one table.

**OUTPUT**

*First Statement Output*

```
 [Number] |[Dep]  |[Join M]  |[Join B]  |[Resign M ]|[Resign B]
 10003    |M      |20160101  |20160201  |20160301   |20160301
 10004    |M      |20160101  |20160201  |20160301   |20160401
```

*Second Statement Output*

```
 [Number] |[Dep]  |[Join M]  |[Join B]  |[Resign M ]|[Resign B]
 10000    |M      |20160201  |20160201  |20160131   |20160430
 10002    |M      |20160501  |20160430  |20160430   |20160430
```

**REQUIRED OUTPUT**

```
 [Number] |[Dep] |[Join M]  |[Join B]  |[Resign M ]|[Resign B]|[Comment]
 10000    |M     |20160201  |20160201  |20160131   |20160430  |'Date'
 10002    |M     |20160501  |20160430  |20160430   |20160430  |'Date'
 10003    |M     |20160101  |20160201  |20160301   |20160301  |'Main'
 10003    |M     |20160101  |20160201  |20160301   |20160401  |'Main'
```

Comment: Thank you to both answers, they are both the same and the exact output I require. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` to combine multiple (compatible) result sets, and you can add extra expressions in the `SELECT` clause

```
SELECT [Number],[Dep],[Join M],[Join B],[Resign M ],[Resign B],'Main' as Comment
FROM [Table] WHERE [Dep]        = 'M'      AND 
                            ([Join M]   <> [Join B] OR   
                            [Resign M]  <> [Resign Date Beneficiary]) 
UNION ALL

SELECT [Number],[Dep],[Join M],[Join B],[Resign M ],[Resign B],'Date' as Comment
FROM [Table] WHERE [Join B]   < [Resign B]  AND
                            ([Join M]  > [Join B]    OR 
                            [Resign M] < [Resign B])
```

Alternatively, if these rows represent the entire contents of `Table` and you just want to classify rows as either `Main` or `Date`, you could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT [Number],[Dep],[Join M],[Join B],[Resign M ],[Resign B],
  CASE WHEN [Dep]        = 'M'      AND 
            ([Join M]   <> [Join B] OR   
            [Resign M]  <> [Resign Date Beneficiary])
  THEN 'Main'
  ELSE 'Date' END as Comment
FROM [Table]
```

Answer (score 1):

seems you just want a union all between the queries

```
SELECT
      [Number]
    , [Dep]
    , [Join M]
    , [Join B]
    , [Resign M ]
    , [Resign B]
    , 'Main' AS comment
FROM [Table]
WHERE [Dep] = 'M'
      AND ([Join M] <> [Join B]
        OR [Resign M] <> [Resign Date Beneficiary]
      )

UNION ALL

      SELECT
            [Number]
          , [Dep]
          , [Join M]
          , [Join B]
          , [Resign M ]
          , [Resign B]
          , 'Date' AS comment
      FROM [Table]
      WHERE [Join B] < [Resign B]
            AND ([Join M] > [Join B]
              OR [Resign M] < [Resign B]
                )
;
```